# Attempted to call function \"exif_read_data\"

Tags: php, dockerfile, symfony4, exif, php-extension

So I am running a symfony application where I need the exif_read_data(). I have enabled the extension in php.ini file but for some reason the extension is not loaded.

## **Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:7.3.27-fpm-buster

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y libzip-dev jed git less unzip zlib1g-dev supervisor nano mc locales wget mailutils \
        whois \
        host \
        apt-transport-https \
        curl \
        ca-certificates \
        # required for intl
        libicu-dev \
        #apache2 \
        # needed for apache config
        libapache2-mod-fcgid \
        #apache2-modmacro \
        # required for gd
        libpng-dev \
        # required for curl
        libcurl4-openssl-dev \
        # required for xml
        libxml2-dev \
        # required for soap
        imagemagick \
        libmagickwand-dev \
        zip \
        #required for memcache
        libmemcached-dev zlib1g-dev \
        #required for xslt processing
        libxslt-dev \
        #zlib-dev  cyrus-sasl-dev \
        libwebp-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libpng-dev libxpm-dev libfreetype6-dev \
        # required for imap
        libc-client-dev libkrb5-dev \
        gettext \
        && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) xsl gettext soap mysqli pcntl pdo_mysql curl intl xml opcache zip sockets bcmath \
        #&& pecl install memcache \
        #&& docker-php-ext-enable memcache \
        && pecl install memcached \
        && docker-php-ext-enable opcache \
        && docker-php-ext-enable memcached \
        && docker-php-ext-enable gettext \
        && pecl install apcu \
        && docker-php-ext-enable apcu \
        && pecl install xdebug-2.8.0 \
        && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
        && pecl install redis-4.0.1 \
        && docker-php-ext-enable redis \
        && pecl install imagick \
        && docker-php-ext-enable imagick \
        && docker-php-ext-configure imap --with-kerberos --with-imap-ssl \
        && docker-php-ext-install imap \
        && pecl install pcov \
        && docker-php-ext-enable pcov \
        && apt-get clean
# configure and install gd
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd --with-webp-dir --with-jpeg-dir \
    --with-png-dir --with-zlib-dir --with-xpm-dir --with-freetype-dir
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

RUN docker-php-ext-install mbstring
RUN docker-php-ext-enable mbstring

COPY php.ini /etc/php/7.3.27/php.ini
COPY php-fpm-pool.conf /etc/php/7.3.27/pool.d/www.conf

RUN curl -sSk https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --disable-tls && \
   mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

RUN groupadd dev -g 999
RUN useradd dev -g dev -d /home/dev -m

RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" > /etc/locale.gen && \
    echo "fr_FR.UTF-8 UTF-8" >> /etc/locale.gen && \
    locale-gen

WORKDIR /service/wwwroot/

EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

## **php.ini**

```
extension=mbstring
extension=exif
```

Running the following command inside the container terminal seems to show that the exif extension was not loaded.

```
php -r "print_r(get_loaded_extensions());" | grep exif
```

Error Message from Symfony:

```
{
"status": 500,
    "detail": "Attempted to call function \"exif_read_data\" from namespace \"App\\Controller\\API\".",
    "class": "Symfony\\Component\\ErrorHandler\\Error\\UndefinedFunctionError",
}
```

I have exhausted almost all methods checked installation of mbstring and the order it was enabled in the php.ini file. Everything seems to be ok but still it doesnt work.

Comment: You never do `docker-php-ext-install exif` in your Dockerfile...

Comment: I dont know how I missed it damn!